# array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Tags: php, arrays, upload

I've got a problem with my code that I've been struggling with. I just can't figure out what causes this error.

So, I made an upload form in my CMS. If I upload 9 photos, it works fine. If I upload beyond 9 files, it gives me this error:

```
array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:...upload.php on line 18
```

Can somebody help me out?

Code:

```
$file_ary = reArrayFiles($_FILES['ufile']);
  //Reorganising the $_FILES:

  function reArrayFiles(&$file_post) {

      $file_ary = array();
      $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
      $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

      for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
          foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
              $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
          }
      }

      return $file_ary;
  }


  foreach ($file_ary as $file) {
      $dir = "imgs/" . $last_fotoid . "/";

      if (!file_exists($dir)) {
        mkdir("imgs/" . $last_fotoid . "/");
      }


      $target_file = $dir . basename($file["name"]); 

      move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $target_file);

}
```

My form:

```
<form  method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          Select image to upload:<br>
          <input type="file" name="ufile[]" multiple>
          <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: the code you've copied doesn't help much. But basically you need to make sure when calling **reArrayFiles** method, you are passing an array

Comment: $_FILES['ufile'] is an array, so it should work

Comment: well, not always, only when you submitting the form. it's not possible to say looking at the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly pointed to `$file_keys = array_keys($file_post);` so defiantly there is a case where you are calling **reArrayFiles()** method but with a null argument instead of the expected array (of files in this case). you can confirm this by checking the value of `$_FILES['ufile']` before passing it to your method.

Is this happen when you are visiting the page with the form in it? or it only happens when you submit the form? Not seeing your full code it's difficult to be %100, but I'm thinking you've forgotten to execute your code **only if it is a POST request** as the result of the form submission.

Basically make sure you start the process only when you have received the expected files.

Comment: This code works fine when I'm uploading 9 files. Beyond that I'm getting this error messages. The files are also not being uploaded.

Comment: I just put up a demo and gave it a try, and managed to replicate the same error. But not because of number of file but because of failing the upload process by including a large file